# jmap command not found

Tags: java, linux, centos

I'm trying to use the `jmap` command on my `CentOS` server but it keeps telling me that the command was not found even though I have the JDK installed.

Here is the output of command `java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.10.4.el6_4-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you find jmap using  "locate jmap" ??

Comment: Install the JDK, not the JRE. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jmap.html

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to find **jmap** in the *java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug*, or *java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-debug*, or *java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-debug* packages on Redhat/Centos.  To install it, run the following as root:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug
```

For completeness, here's the command to check which packages include jmap:

```
yum whatprovides '*/jmap'
```

Here's a sample output:

```
1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.37-1.13.9.4.el7_1.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.37.x86_64/bin/jmap



1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.91-2.6.2.3.el7.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91-2.6.2.3.el7.x86_64/bin/jmap



1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64/bin/jmap



1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment with full debug on
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64-debug/bin/jmap



1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment with full debug on
Repo        : @base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64-debug/bin/jmap
```

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-dbg`

Answer (score 7):

My situation was a little strange (running inside the `openjdk:8-jre` Docker image), but this combination worked

```
cat /etc/debian_version # 8.6
apt install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jre-headless ca-certificates-java
apt-get install -f -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless
apt-get install -f -y openjdk-8-dbg
```

Comment: Same situation here, and your commands worked.  But I cannot find jmap anywhere on the machine, post-install.  Definitely not in the jdk/jre bin directories for any of the installations.

Comment: If the `jmap` command works, you can try `which jmap` to get the path to the binary.

Comment: I was getting `The value 'jessie-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release`. I had to add `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

the java path must be in the "PATH" systemproperty.

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't come default with JRE -- you should be able to install it with below command

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug
```

Answer (score 1):

for Debian "buster" - 10.3 -

```
cat /etc/debian_version # 10.3

echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster.list

apt-get update && apt-get install -f -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-dbg
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that on my system (elasticsearch container) it is excluded:

```
$ grep exclude /etc/yum.conf 
exclude=java-1.8.0-openjdk*
```

If I comment it out then I can see and install this package with `yum install ...`