# Which java 8 docker image contains jmap?

Tags: java, docker

I'm want to use `jmap` but the docker image java:8-jre doesn't have it. Which java docker image would have it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make your own image with:

```
RUN apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-dbg
```

The dbg one will include `jmap` (see "[`jmap` command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25715067/6309)")

Answer (score 3):

Just do a search in the docker hub, such as `site:hub.docker.com java jmap` and you should find many.

Check that the associated Dockerfile contains jmap